# Displaying a series of pictures (JPanels with images) in a horizontal sequence

Tags: java, image, swing, embedded-resource

I have been looking for a way to display images on a JPanel in a grid-like fashion, and came across [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222988/java-drag-and-drop-images-in-a-list). The code works very well but when I attempted to modify it by using `jpg` images instead of drawing rectangles, I could't get it to work. My modification is as follows:

```
/*
 * courtesy of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222988/java-drag-and-drop-images-  in-a-list
 */

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class ImagePreviewList {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Image panel");
    frame.setSize(800, 300);
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    JList imageList = createImageList();
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(imageList));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private static JList createImageList() {

    JList imageList = new JList(createModel());
    imageList.setCellRenderer(new ImageCellRenderer());
    imageList.setLayoutOrientation(JList.HORIZONTAL_WRAP);
    imageList.setVisibleRowCount(-1);
    imageList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    imageList.setFixedCellWidth(240);
    imageList.setFixedCellHeight(120);

    imageList.setDragEnabled(true);
    imageList.setDropMode(DropMode.INSERT);
    imageList.setTransferHandler(new ImageTransferHandler(imageList));

    return imageList;
}

private static DefaultListModel createModel() {
    DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
    model.addElement(new RTS_image("3-Way_Stop_sign"));
    model.addElement(new RTS_image("4-Way_Stop_sign"));
    model.addElement(new RTS_image("No_Entry_sign"));
    model.addElement(new RTS_image("One-Way_Roadway_sign-0"));
    model.addElement(new RTS_image("One-Way_Roadway_sign-1"));
    model.addElement(new RTS_image("One-Way_Roadway_sign-3"));
    model.addElement(new RTS_image("Pedestrian-Priority_sign"));
    model.addElement(new RTS_image("Stop#Go_sign"));
    model.addElement(new RTS_image("Stop_and_Yield_sign"));
    model.addElement(new RTS_image("Stop_sign-0"));
    model.addElement(new RTS_image("Stop_sign-1"));
    model.addElement(new RTS_image("Yield_at_Mini-Circle_sign"));
    model.addElement(new RTS_image("Yield_sign"));
    model.addElement(new RTS_image("Yield_to_Pedestrians_sign"));
    model.addElement(new RTS_image("Yield_to_oncoming_traffic_sign"));
    return model;
}

static class ImageTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {

    private static final DataFlavor DATA_FLAVOUR = new DataFlavor(RTS_image.class,  "Images");

    private final JList previewList;
    private boolean inDrag;

    ImageTransferHandler(JList previewList) {
        this.previewList = previewList;
    }

    public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
        return TransferHandler.MOVE;
    }

    protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent c) {
        inDrag = true;
        return new Transferable() {
            public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
                return new DataFlavor[] {DATA_FLAVOUR};
            }

            public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
                return flavor.equals(DATA_FLAVOUR);
            }

            public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor) throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException {
                return previewList.getSelectedValue();
            }
        };
    }

    public boolean canImport(TransferSupport support) {
        if (!inDrag || !support.isDataFlavorSupported(DATA_FLAVOUR)) {
            return false;
        }

        JList.DropLocation dl = (JList.DropLocation)support.getDropLocation();
        if (dl.getIndex() == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public boolean importData(TransferSupport support) {
        if (!canImport(support)) {
            return false;
        }

        Transferable transferable = support.getTransferable();
        try {
            Object draggedImage = transferable.getTransferData(DATA_FLAVOUR);

            JList.DropLocation dl = (JList.DropLocation)support.getDropLocation();
            DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel)previewList.getModel();
            int dropIndex = dl.getIndex();
            if (model.indexOf(draggedImage) < dropIndex) {
                dropIndex--;
            }
            model.removeElement(draggedImage);
            model.add(dropIndex, draggedImage);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    protected void exportDone(JComponent source, Transferable data, int action) {
        super.exportDone(source, data, action);
        inDrag = false;
    }
}

static class ImageCellRenderer extends JPanel implements ListCellRenderer {

    DefaultListCellRenderer defaultListCellRenderer = new DefaultListCellRenderer();
    JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel();
    JLabel descriptionLabel = new JLabel();

    ImageCellRenderer() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Border emptyBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5);
        imageLabel.setBorder(emptyBorder);
        descriptionLabel.setBorder(emptyBorder);
        add(imageLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(descriptionLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        defaultListCellRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        setBorder(defaultListCellRenderer.getBorder());
        setBackground(defaultListCellRenderer.getBackground());
        imageLabel.setIcon((Icon)value);
        descriptionLabel.setText("Description");
        return this;
    }
}

static class RTS_image implements Icon, Serializable {
    private String Name_of_RoadSign; 

    RTS_image(String name_of_roadsign) {
        this.Name_of_RoadSign = name_of_roadsign;
    }

    java.net.URL imgURL = com.umusebo.RTS.ImagePreviewList.class.getResource("images/01_Regulatory_Signs/01_Control_Signs/reg_cont_" + Name_of_RoadSign + ".jpg");

    Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(imgURL);

    public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        g.drawImage(img, x, y, c);
    }

    public int getIconWidth() {
        return 114;
    }

    public int getIconHeight() {
        return 125;
    }

    public String getName_of_RoadSign() {
        return Name_of_RoadSign;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        return Name_of_RoadSign.equals(((RTS_image)o).Name_of_RoadSign);
    }

}
```

}

Upon execution I get the following errors (which repeats 15 times for the 15 images I'm trying to display):

```
Uncaught error fetching image:
java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getConnection(URLImageSource.java:115)
at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getDecoder(URLImageSource.java:125)
at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(InputStreamImageSource.java:263)
at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(ImageFetcher.java:205)
at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(ImageFetcher.java:169)
```

Where could the problem be?

Comment: There is nothing in the title to suggest D'n'D is needed.  Do the items need to be draggable?  If so look at `JList`.

Comment: @Andrew I don't necessarily need them to be draggable, in fact I changed the code to read `imageList.setDragEnabled(false);` at line 40.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've declared a number of class level field that you are trying to initialise using the values from other variables that are `null`

For example, you are declaring and intialising `imgURL` from the variable `Name_of_RoadSign`, which will be `null`.

```
java.net.URL imgURL = com.umusebo.RTS.ImagePreviewList.class.getResource(
    "images/01_Regulatory_Signs/01_Control_Signs/reg_cont_"
    + Name_of_RoadSign + ".jpg");
```

You have to remember that the classes fields are initialised BEFORE any of the classes constructors are executed.

Try initialising these class variables within constructor instead

```
RTS_image(String name_of_roadsign) {
    this.Name_of_RoadSign = name_of_roadsign;
    imgURL = com.umusebo.RTS.ImagePreviewList.class.getResource(
        "images/01_Regulatory_Signs/01_Control_Signs/reg_cont_"
        + Name_of_RoadSign + ".jpg");
    img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(imgURL);
}
```

`ToolKit#createImage` tends to silently ignore errors and will return a none `null` value even if the image can't be loaded.  You are much better of using `ImageIO` instead.  Apart from the fact that it supports a greater range of image formats, it will also throw more meaningful exceptions, making it easier to diagnose problems.

For example...

```
img = ImageIO.read(imgURL);
```

Don't forget, this will throw an `IOException` so you either need to catch it or (better still) pass it back to the caller.

I would also encourage you to familiarise yourself with the [*Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).  You won't make any friends or influence people by ignoring them. ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have made changes as you suggested [Here are the changes](http://pastie.org/private/2fokejdseq3zjgfbkrumqw). When run, No exceptions are thrown, however, the images are not displayed. Why could this be so?

Comment: Sorry, you've also creating the image out side the constructor, so the URL will also be null.  This tends not raise exceptions, try adding `img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(imgURL);` to the end of the constructor as well.  I would also suggest you use `ImageIO` instead, apart from the fact it supports more image formats, it will also raise exceptions when the image doesn't exist or there is a problem reading the image

Comment: I did realize that the image needed to be created in the constructor and the code in is in the link in my earlier comment. Your suggestion to use `ImageIO` was very valuable, it finally worked! [Here are the full changes I made](http://pastie.org/private/dq0oifj4puadzbbx7mizq#)